# Discord.py how to pin a message in a channel?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying using that code:

```
Message= await ctx.send("Message to pin")
await pin_message(Message)
```

But it gives me that error:

```
NameError: name 'pin_message' is not defined
```

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.pin)

You pin messages with

```py
await message.pin()
```

Comment: Thank you, can you help also in that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608472/discord-py-how-to-pin-a-post-made-by-a-webhook