# Discord.py: How to pin a post made by a webhook?

Tags: discord.py

```
Message= await webhook.send("Test message to pin")
await Message.pin()
```

But I get a str in return from webhook.send. How can I get a message type so I'm able to pin it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: May I suggest that you look at PEP8 also https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ as capitalising your variables is against PEP8 python standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook.send). You will see that you need to add the following parameter: `wait=True` (when sending through a webhook). This will return the message. If you dont do this it will return None as explained in the doc.

Thus what you need to do:

```
Message = await webhook.send("Test message to pin", wait=True)
await Message.pin()
```